# MySQL - Update Select Issues

Tags: mysql, sql

The aim of my query is to use a value from one table A to look up a corresponding value from another table B, and then use that value to look up another value from another table C. This value should then be used to update a column in the original table A.

In my query so far I have managed to get a correct list of the values from table C using this command. In this command, `Disbursements`, `Employee_Details` & `List_State_Codes` correspond to tables A, B & C respectively as described above.

```
SELECT  `List_State_Codes`.`Code` 
FROM  `List_State_Codes` 
LEFT JOIN (
`Employee_Details` ,  `Disbursements`
) ON (  `Employee_Details`.`STATE` =  `List_State_Codes`.`STATE` )   
WHERE  `Employee_Details`.`EmployeeID` =  `Disbursements`.`EmployeeID`
```

This returns the correct list of values as required: One value from table C for each row in table A. Now my issue is to update the required column from table A with these returned values. This is where I am stuck.

The following query is what I believe to be my closest attempt:

```
UPDATE `Disbursements`
SET `Disbursements`.`CostCentreID` =
(
    SELECT  `List_State_Codes`.`Code` 
    FROM  (SELECT * FROM `List_State_Codes`) AS `table` 
    LEFT JOIN (
    `Employee_Details` ,  `Disbursements`
    ) ON (  `Employee_Details`.`STATE` =  `List_State_Codes`.`STATE` ) 
    WHERE  `Employee_Details`.`EmployeeID` =  `Disbursements`.`EmployeeID` 
)
```

I receive the

> error #1093 - You can't specify target table 'Disbursements' for update in FROM clause, despite adding the FROM  (SELECT * FROM List_State_Codes) AS table line.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join in the update, and this can help to remove the offending table from the subquery:

```
UPDATE `Disbursements`
JOIN `Employee_Details` 
   ON `Employee_Details`.`EmployeeID` = `Disbursements`.`EmployeeID`
LEFT JOIN `List_State_Codes`
   ON `Employee_Details`.`STATE` = `List_State_Codes`.`STATE`
SET `Disbursements`.`CostCentreID` = `List_State_Codes`.`Code`
```

However, I could not test this, so let me know if this helps. (or if some other error occurs)

Comment: Thanks Paul. The code as you have given it produces an error `#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'Employee_Details'`. A bit of googling suggested this was an error with table aliases. I think with your help I've found the correct answer!

Comment: I updated the left join clause in my answer above, as I should not have added the `Employee_Details` to the left join. What should have been there instead is the `List_State_Codes`. That change should avoid the `Not unique...` error. (and no table alias need)

Comment: Yes I've just rolled back the changes I made to test your query and it worked perfectly. Thanks again for your help, I will mark it as correct seeing as it is a better solution than mine.

Comment: No problem, at least you noted the double table (because of the unique error). Thanks for accepting!  When I saw what you had to do, that helped me realize my goof.

Comment: It was partly that and partly a desire to fix my own problems rather than relying on others completely. However seeing two solutions to my problem helps me to understand the nature of it better so it's a better outcome overall.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Paul's help I have found the correct solution to my problem. The second join was what I needed as Paul suggested, along with an additional table alias to prevent the classic `#Error 1903`. I also needed to add the `List_State_Codes` (table C) to the `JOIN` to ensure it could access the correct data.

```
UPDATE  `Disbursements` 
JOIN  `Employee_Details` 
     ON `Employee_Details`.`EmployeeID` =  `Disbursements`.`EmployeeID` 
LEFT JOIN (
    `Employee_Details` d,
    `List_State_Codes`
) ON  
     `Employee_Details`.`STATE` =  `List_State_Codes`.`STATE` 
SET `Disbursements`.`CostCentreID` =  `List_State_Codes`.`Code`
```